# Calling variables from HTML form in PHP?

Tags: php, variables, twilio, forms

I have simple HTML file containing a form which asks the user for specific info such as name, contact, location, etc. The form has an action to "send-sms.php" which uses a Twilio API to forward an SMS to my phone.

The text sends properly, but the way I am attempting to call the variables from the HTML form is not getting recognized in my PHP code. In other words, I keep getting the text inside the quotes, but not the values that were submitted into the input boxes. I have included the code below:

```js
<?php
require 'twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php';

$name = $_POST['name'];
$task = $_POST['task'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$location = $_POST['location'];
$misc = $_POST['misc'];

$account_sid = 'AC*******************'; 
$auth_token = 'b********************'; 
$client = new Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token); 
 
$client->account->messages->create(array( 
 'To' => "3177302557", 
 'From' => "+13173644864", 
 'Body' => "YOU GOT A NEW ERRAND, BET!: \n Name: $name \n Task: $task \n Contact: $contact \n Location: $location \n Misc: $misc",   
)); 
?>
```

```html
<form action="send-sms.php" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">1</span> Your Information</legend>
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
        <input type="email" name="field2" id="contact"placeholder="Contact Information (Email, Phone Number, etc.) *">
        <input type="location" name="field3" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, Hodge Hall, exact address, etc.)*">
        <input type="text" name="field4" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important"></textarea>
        <label for="job">Urgency:</label>
        <select id="job" name="field5">
            <optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
                <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
                <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
                <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
            </optgroup>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><span class="number">2</span>Task that needs completion</legend>
        <input type="text" id="task" name="field6" placeholder="Let Us Know How We Can Help!*"></input>
    </fieldset>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onClick="push();validateForm();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm surprised you get anything at all. You have fields with `name="fieldX` and access them as `$_POST['name']`...

Answer (score 2):

`id` attributes in form fields are **NOT** used for form submission. only `name` is:

```
<input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
                          ^^^^^---used for form submission

$foo = $_POST['name']; // warning: undefined index
$foo = $_POST['field1']; // A-OK
```

If you'd done even BASIC debugging, like `var_dump($_POST);`, you'd have seen your error.